# Oracle - query by two column combination

Tags: oracle

I have two tables:

```
    product_table:    
    ------------------------------------
     product | market | category | other
    ------------------------------------
             |        |          |
    ------------------------------------


    availability_table:
    -------------------------------------
     product | num_available | some_other
    -------------------------------------
             |               |
    -------------------------------------
```

I have a list of 7 markets and a list of 41 categories. For each market/category combination, I need to get several products (3 is a good number) that are currently available. I came up with a query that delivers products for one market/category combination:

```
SELECT product_table.product, product_table.category
FROM product_table, availability_table
WHERE   product_table.market = 1 // market is changing from query to query
    AND product_table.product = availability_table.product
    AND availability_table.num_available > 0
    AND product_table.category = 'category_1' // category is changing from query to query
    AND ROWNUM <= 3
```

This works well for one market/category combination, but I have to manually submit 287 queries to get all data I need. Is there any way to build a query that will do it for me with one submission?

Comment: Do you really not care which three products you get for each market & category?

Comment: Don't care, they are for testing purposes. I just need three that are available.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't care which products are returned

```
SELECT product, category, market
  FROM (SELECT product, 
               category,
               market,
               row_number() over (partition by market, category
                                      order by rownum) rnk
          FROM product_table
               JOIN availability_table USING (product)
         WHERE num_available > 0)
 WHERE rnk <= 3;
```

Comment: Justin, thanks for your update. I ran this query, and the job failed after runnning for 5 hours with a message that the server cannot find some object any more. I think some database component hit a timout. Maybe if the database was smaller, it would work, not sure. The lesson I have learned from this attempt is that I need to actually sit down and study SQL, instead of getting pieces of information here and there.